# Запятая после "так"

Tags: пунктуация

> Человек, который заказывает художникам произведения искусств, во имя
>   прославления Бога, и оплачивает их, называется *донатор*. И такого
>   героя легко узнать: он или присутствует на иконе, в своём современном
>   костюме, как участник событий Священной истории, или держит в руках
>   своё приношение – так папа Феликс IV (526–530) держит в руках храм, в
>   котором мы и находимся.

*...так, папа Феликс IV (526–530) держит в руках храм, в котором мы и находимся.*

Все другие запятые - авторские.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Так** (например)**, папа Феликс IV (526–530) держит в руках храм, в котором мы и находимся.**

Не было бы запятой, если бы папа держал так, как кто-то другой (сравнение).

Comment: Что смущает: *...или держит в руках своё приношение – так папа Феликс IV (526–530) держит в руках храм...* Не может ли быть, что именно ***как***: некто держит нечто, как папа Феликс...

Comment: Оба ответа верны, спросите у автора

Answer (score 2):

> И такого героя легко узнать

На мой взгляд, необходимо добавить: "на иконе". Я бы предложил "легко обнаружить на иконе". Но тогда все надо перестраивать.

> в своём современном костюме

Современный - это из 21-века. А он в костюме своего времени.

**Человек, который заказывает художникам произведения искусств, во имя прославления Бога, и оплачивает их, называется донатор. И такого героя легко [обнаружить на иконе: он присутствует, в костюме своего времени], как участник событий Священной истории, или держит в руках своё приношение – так, папа Феликс IV (526–530) держит в руках храм, в котором мы и находимся.**

Comment: Да там об одних иконах (фресках) речь; и ваще - правка (читай: влезание в чужую шкуру) всегда должна быть минимальной. А  вопросы мне (по публикуемому вопросу) задавать нельзя: это отвлекает меня от работы - у меня ж параллельно текст раскрыт.

Comment: Кому вопросы и кто не может(нельзя ему) их задавать?

Comment: Ми-не. Мине низзя. Отвлекает. А ответов-то у мине усё одно нетути.